# New-PSSession :Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed :The parameter is incorrect

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following command on a server(running on Windows Server 2012 R2) in order to import the exchange online PowerShell(I am using the PowerShell ISE with version 5 of PowerShell) commands such as "Search-UnifiedAuditLog" but whenever I run the command I receive an error. My code works while on my local machine(Windows 7 with PowerShell V4) but when I remote connect onto the server to try and run the command it doesn't work.

I am aiming to have a script including this command run as a scheduled task which is why it needs run on the server. I've tried to run this command on several user accounts on the server and still get the same issue. Running the command using the same user accounts as before but using my local machine does not result in an error.

I have tried to set the execution policy to RemoteSigned using the following command but this has had no effect.
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force

My current code looks like;

```
$ExchangeCredentials = Get-StoredCredential -Target Credentials

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $ExchangeCredentials -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
```

The full error I receive is;

```
New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : The parameter is incorrect. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:12
+ $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conne ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 87,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

I'd expect this command to run fine like on my local machine. I've not been able to find anyone else with this same issue.

Comment: Two things to check: 1)Get-StoredCredential isn't a native PowerShell command so maybe that is causing the issue. 2) Change URL to only be "/powershell/"

Comment: does `$ExchangeCredentials` returns `pscredential` object? do `$ExchangeCredentials.GetType()` and show the results...

Comment: Have you tested this with the PowerShell console rather than ISE?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent - 1) The same command works using my local machine so I don't believe this is the issue.
2) I've just tried this and I got the same error sadly

Comment: @AdminOfThings - Yip, I've tried these commands in both areas and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, `New-PSSession` is causing the issue. As all the other parameters look correct, I would check what you are passing to the `Credential` parameter.

Does `Get-StoredCredential -Target Credentials` obtain a correct `PSCredential` object?

Comment: @Avshalom - I've just had a look and it looks fine to me, the same command works on my local machine. I've double check that the username and password are correct as well just incase.
`
IsPublic     IsSerial         Name               BaseType                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                     
True              True      PSCredential      System.Object `